# Automatic swipe & screenshot in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, libimobiledevice

Is there any way to swipe & take screenshots in iPhone programmatically, like what can be done in Android like:

```
while condition:
    adb shell input touchscreen swipe x1 y1 x2 y2 t
    adb exec-out screencap -p > screen.png
```

...?

I only know that `idevicescreenshot` in `libimobiledevice` can be used to take screenshots, but it seems like this lib cannot be used to simulate input events according to [this issue](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/385).